# How do I create group data in a category with more than and less than in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set and I would like to group them in a category... But I would like the category to be more than and less than a certain number?

This is my data set.

```
"gridcellname","lat","lon","avg.temp"
"Y12X46",68.79,37.798,6.93684
"Y13X49",68.973,39.706,8.9314
"Y14X49",69.197,39.755,5.7867
"Y14X50",69.178,40.386,5.48162
"Y14X53",69.106,42.271,4.1848
"Y14X54",69.078,42.896,3.7789
```

I would like the last column to be like:

```
"gridcellname","lat","lon","avg.temp","temp_category"
"Y12X46",68.79,37.798,6.93684,(6>)
"Y13X49",68.973,39.706,8.9314,(6>)
"Y14X49",69.197,39.755,5.7867,(5,6]
"Y14X50",69.178,40.386,5.48162,(5,6]
"Y14X53",69.106,42.271,4.1848,(4,5]
"Y14X54",69.078,42.896,3.7789,(<4)
"Y40X44",75.102,37.191,1.99166,(<4)
```

I know how to categorize according to breaks with individual temperatures.

```
df<- cbind(df, temp_category=cut(df$avg.temp, breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```

But I want to only group 4,5,6 and the rest put into <4 and >6. Is this possible in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df<- cbind(df, temp_category=cut(df$avg.temp, breaks=c(-Inf,4,5,6,Inf)))
#the following is more idiomatic
df$temp_category <- cut(df$avg.temp, breaks=c(-Inf,4,5,6,Inf))
```

Comment: If you remove `cbind` and just assign to a column, you get an upvote from me.

Comment: yes it does :) thank you Blue!
I do not understand what you meant by remove cbind - Roland...

Comment: @Bala Roland means that there is a more concise way to write the code. See my edit.

Comment: yup got it! Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I have another question: Is it possible to tell R to split the numbers accordingly... e.g ....., breaks=c(-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2)) This is too time consuming to write... How do I say that I want it from -2 to 2 with 0.5 intervals?

Comment: @Bala R has the function `?seq` and the operator `?\`:\``. You could code `seq(-2,2,.5)` or `(-4:4)/2`.